# I want to check whether a new file is added to firebase storage or not

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I want to check whether a new file is added to Firebase Storage or not, as I will be using the test case to show the updated image in the android app developed in Java and showing no new file added if that no the case.

Comment: I am not able to get your question properly, As I understood you are using Firebase Storage in your app and you want to check recently uploaded file is available on storage or not. Right

Comment: thanks! for responding , Actually I am creating an home work app in which I will be uploading the images ,then I am retrieving that file in android app. now I want to show the message if new image was not uploaded that no homework for today and if image uploaded then that file will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check whether a new file is added to Firebase Storage or not.

If you want that, then you have to know when you have the file was added to the storage for the first time. For that, I recommend you store the details of the files either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database).

Now, when you want to upload a file, first you have to check if the file already exists, before performing the upload operation. If the file doesn't exist, then you have to upload it, otherwise, do whatever you want.

Comment: thanks! for responding , Actually I am creating an home work app in which I will be uploading the images ,then I am retrieving that file in android app. now I want to show the message if new image was not uploaded that no homework for today and if image uploaded then that file will be shown.

Comment: That's good. You can go ahead and use this solution for that.

Comment: Hey Pradeep. Can I help you with other information?